# .NET 6 API with multiple schemes work but gives errors in log

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have an API that uses 3 AuthenticationSchemes (basic authentication, AD authentication and JWT token authentication).

These are registered in the startup.cs:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AuthSchemes.BasicAuthScheme)
    .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, BasicAuthenticationHandler>(AuthSchemes.BasicAuthScheme, null);

services
  .AddAuthentication(AuthSchemes.ADAuthScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(AuthSchemes.JWTTokenAuthScheme, options =>
  {
      options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
      {
          ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
          ValidateAudience = false,
          ValidateIssuer = false,
          IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(appSettings.ApiTokenSecurityKey))
      };
  })
  .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(_configuration.GetSection("AzureActiveDirectory"));
```

AuthSchemes:

```
public const string BasicAuthScheme = "BasicAuthentication";
public const string ADAuthScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
public const string JWTTokenAuthScheme = "JWTTokenAuthScheme";

public const string AllAuthSchemes = ADAuthScheme + "," + JWTTokenAuthScheme;
```

I have some endpoints that use the `Authorize` property to tell which schemes can access the endpoint.
Everything is working, but when I check my API logs I'm getting a lot of errors:

[image]

[image]

If I delete one of the `ADAuthScheme` or `JWTTokenAuthScheme` schemes I'm not getting any errors.

Can someone point me in the right direction what could be wrong here?
I'm guessing the call checks both Scheme's and gives errors, even when the other Scheme is succesfull.

Comment: set  IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true; and check the log again,also, provide your appsttings.json